# Trouble writing to App.Config file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Having issues reading/writing to App.config.

The code I have below I took from the MSDN article on (AppSettingsSection Class) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I am successfully able to read the App.config file and get/use the values and it responds correctly if I change the App.config file to get the new values.

However, in this (from MS page) I add a new entry and change a value on one of my initial entries.  It appears to change it, does not error in saving it, but does not write it to the file so the next time I run, I am back to my initial values in App.config.

Can someone show me my erroneous ways?

TIA!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

' IMPORTANT: To compile this example, you must add to the project 
' a reference to the System.Configuration assembly.
'
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim KeypairHolder As String = Nothing
        ' Get Configuration File as config object
        Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

        ' Create a unique key/value pair to add to the appSettings section.
        Dim keyName As String = "DateTimeStamp Number " & config.AppSettings.Settings.Count + 1
        Dim value As String = String.Concat(Date.Now.ToLongDateString(), " ", Date.Now.ToLongTimeString())

        ' Create appSettings as object
        Dim appSettings As System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection = config.AppSettings

        ' add the new key and value 
        appSettings.Settings.Add(keyName, value)

        ' save and refresh the values
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)

        ' Force a reload in memory of the changed section.
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")

        ' Get keys
        Dim kAll() As String = appSettings.Settings.AllKeys()

        ' Build string to display
        For Each key In kAll
            KeypairHolder = KeypairHolder & key & ":  " & appSettings.Settings(key).Value & vbCrLf
        Next

        'Display
        MsgBox(KeypairHolder)

        ' Change a value
        appSettings.Settings("CustomKey").Value = "Changed Value"

        ' Resave and get and display
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
        kAll = appSettings.Settings.AllKeys()
        KeypairHolder = Nothing
        For Each key In kAll
            KeypairHolder = KeypairHolder & key & ":  " & appSettings.Settings(key).Value & vbCrLf
        Next
        MsgBox(KeypairHolder)

    End Sub
End Module

' appSettings Section of my App.Config file
'   <appSettings>
'    <add key="UsernamePassword" value="BobsUsername:BobsPassword"/>
'    <add key="CustomKey" value="ConfigApp Value"/>
'  </appSettings>
```

Comment: I am aware of the AppName.exe.config files that are created, but they remain as App.config...  Unchanged...

Comment: A tutorial on YouTube states that READING from appConfig is native out of the box in .NET but WRITING is not...  :(

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the app.config file in your solution explorer window and select the **Properties** option.  Ensure that the **Copy to Output Directory** property is NOT set to **Copy always**.

Comment: It was on Do not copy, but I tried all three with the same effect.